# bindinglist datagridview value change listener

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, bindingsource

I have BindingSource that uses BindingList< MyObject > as a data source. Two identical data grids are using the same binding source. When I change a cell in the first grid it automatically changes also in the second grid. What I need is how to track which object is changed via event listener. Because the two datagridviews are attached to the same binding source and changing a value in the one grid reflects in the other, this means the binding source detects the change and updates the other grid right ?
How can I listen to this kind of changes pragmatically ? I tried with CurrentChanged, CurrentItemChanged, ListChanged but it does not fire when I change a cell value and move the next cell (not the next row)

Comment: `CellEndEdit` might be one way from what you describe.  The reason you only see it row by row is that the DGV does not update the list until you leave the row.  Until then, changes are tentative.  You can see this using a class with `INotifyPropertyChanged` implemented - the underlying list values are not updated until you leave the row.

Comment: okay so you want to check if any property of the object which is inside BindingList has changed ?? I will say you may need to drive your particlar object class form INotifyProperyChange interface..